# Prevent application from changing file associations

Tags: kubuntu, snap, skype, file-association

I recently installed Skype on Kubuntu 20.04 via *snap* and I discovered that it added itself at the end of the list of applications associated with **every single file type on the system**! Of course, this means that for the many file types recognised by the system that don't currently have an application associated with them or unknown file types, Skype became the default application.

The only practical way I found of undoing this (*practical* meaning not manually going through every single file type) was to completely uninstall Skype.

Is there a way of preventing an application from doing this? Or at least, is there a simple way of undoing this after the fact?

This example is specific to Skype on *snap*, but I'd prefer a general answer (i.e., that would apply to any app on *snap* or in general) if it exists. The only answers I've seen related to similar issues with file-type associations are application-specific, so not helpful in this case.

**System**:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.15.0-46-generic

Comment: Ugh, that's terrible. Consider filing a bug against Skype, or providing feedback some other way. Applications should not be doing that, and developers should be made aware of this.

Comment: @marcelm Hah, the Skype devs don't care. They used to install Skype bundled with a browser extension that turned every email address or phone number (not just links, but anything that matched the regex `\d{3}-\d{4}`, basically) into a Skype link. And *that* thing was hard to uninstall. Point is, they're not exactly subtle about the fact that their software is only one step above adware on the moral hierarchy.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo And if no one cares enough to complain, things will never change. If enough people do voice their dismay, at least there's a chance.

Comment: @marcelm are you suggesting something useless to encourage people to feel helpless? consider *not using skype*, that actually works

Comment: @amara I don't know where you're getting that. I'm saying that if enough people complain, something may change, but if no one ever complains, it certainly won't change. (Personally, I don't use Skype, but I appreciate that that is not an option for some people)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made the same experience and looked for a solution a while ago, so here is what I did and it works pretty well so far.
The snap needs to be installed to do this.

First copy the corresponding `.desktop`-file to your home directory with

```
cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Now edit `~/.local/share/applications/skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop`
and remove the line

```
MimeType=application/octet-stream;
```

from the file and save it. As a last step make sure, that the `.desktop`-file has execute permissions:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop
```

Done!

Of course, instead of using terminal commands, you can do the whole thing using your file manager.

**Some side notes:**

The `MimeType`-line in `.desktop`-files tells the system which mime types are supported by an application. This information is used to populate the open-with-lists.

The mime type `application/octet-stream` seems to be a bit special, since you can open any file as an `application/octet-stream`. I think that's the reason why the application is added to the open-with-list for any type of file.

`.desktop`-files with the same name in `~/.local/share/applications` take precedence over `.desktop`-files in the system-wide locations like `/usr/share/applications` (for deb-packages) and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` (for snaps).

A `.desktop`-file in `~/.local/share/applications` will not get overridden by reinstalling or upgrading an application.

If you want to dive deeper into the topic, I'd recommend to take a look at the [freedesktop.org/specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/). This whole thing is widely used under Linux, especially under KDE, Gnome and xfce.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! But because I'm a curious bunny, adding to the answer some further details as to why/how exactly this works would be even better, if you don't mind. For example, I'm guessing files in ~/.local/ override same files in other locations. But what does the MimeType line do exactly? Links to docs/references are also fine.

Comment: @Ratler Sorry for the delay, I had an accident. But finally, I added some information for you to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I hope you're OK.